# Interface variable not able to access all class methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have one interface and a class see below:

```
interface ILastName
    {
        string LastName();
    }
    class MyName:ILastName
    {
        public string FirstName()
        {
            return "Michael";
        }
        public string LastName()
        {
            return "Dutt";
        }
    }
```

Now see my following questions and assumptions
1)

```
 MyName myNameObj=new MyName();
```

in the above line of code `new Myname()` helps to create Object of class and it allocate memory in the heap that means all the method of `MyName` is present in heap for access. and `myNameObj` contain reference to that memory so means we can access all the method by using `myNameObj`. (name of method).

But
 2)

```
 ILastName obj=new MyName();
```

In the above line same thing happen `new Myname()` creating object of class n taking memory in heap that means all method available to access in heap.

But we are able to  access only those  methods which are present in Interface see following line  I can access

```
obj.LastName();
```

But following is not possible why?

```
obj.FirstName();
```

Why? obj is also holding the reference to the memory which is taken by `MyName` class in heap same as `myNameObj`, then we are not able to access method which is not present in interface?

Comment: Because you declare `obj`, the variable through which you access your instance, as `ILastName`. If you want to access the `FirstName()` method, you'll need to cast `obj` to `MyName` as such: `((MyName)obj).FirstName()`, but not all `ILastName` are `MyName`.

Comment: That is compile-time restriction. If you cast it, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between compile-time Type and run-time Type. The run-time Type of obj is MyName, while the compile-time Type is ILastName.
What if I did the following?

```
class MySecondName:ILastName
{
    public string SecondName()
    {
        return "Michael";
    }
    public string LastName()
    {
        return "Dutt";
    }
}

ILastName obj;
int i = new Random().Next() % 2;
if (i == 0) obj = new MyName();
else obj = new MySecondName();
```

There's no way to tell what the type of obj will be. All that is known is that it's a ILastName, so the only method it is known to have is LastName().

Even if there's only 1 possible Type, as in your example, the compiler will not look at that. The only thing it considers is the compile-time Type.

Comment: agreed with you, i think its creating mapping between and type and object what are the method present in ILastName it map to MyName class and while we write MyName myname=new MyName () it map all the method present in MyName class to MyName.

Comment: Fun: declare obj as dynamic and call obj.FirstName(). You'll get an exception only 50% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the variable `obj` is typed as a `ILastName`.

Hence, all properties, methods, etc. from `ILastName` are visible. They are there, but you need to cast it to the right type in order to access them.

If you try this, it works:

```
MyName obj = new MyName();
```

This would work too:

```
var obj = new MyName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Only what is in the interface ILastName is available for the obj(ILastName obj=new MyName();) usage. The interface only know the method(string LastName();) therefore only can access what is in the interface.

MyName myNameObj=new MyName(); is an object from MyName class, therefore it is able to access all the methods and variables in the MyName.

MyName:ILastName shows MyName is a class implement from the ILastName interface therefore it have to implement all methods in the ILastName .

MyName myNameObj=new MyName(); and ILastName obj=new MyName();
creates object therefore the are memory allocated to it.

Hope my explanation aids your understanding.